# How to define a Kotlin Sequence that is ordered

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way to set the state of a `Sequence` in Kotlin to tell it that the data is ordered?

I know I can create a Kotlin `Sequence` as follows:

```
generateSequence(0) { it + 1 }.windowed(size = 100, step = 1)
```

I imagine that some operations on this sequence are more efficient if it is known that the sequence is ordered. For example, `distinct()`. If the sequence is not in order, temporary storage would need to be used. Is there a way to generate this sequence and tell Kotlin that we know the data is already sorted?

Comment: No, Kotlin has no concept of ordered sequences.

Comment: Hmm, that's unfortunate. There are a number of cases where sequence operations would be more efficient depending on such knowledge. I guess, in looking at the code now (https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Sequences.kt#L521), it does appear that it always assumes unordered.

Comment: I agree, would be a nice thing to add to the language. In the meantime, I guess adding an `interface OrderedSequence : Sequence` and defining the operations you need yourself is your best bet (unless you find a library that already does this for you)

Answer (score 1):

sort sequence, then convert to the list

```
var sortedList = mySequence.sortedBy { i -> i.sortedProperty }.toList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since sequences are lazy and potentially infinite, any concept of ordering besides the *sequence* ordering is going to be wicked to handle. When iterating, how can you ever know that you've found the next (largest) value?
That is, it's not even clear that "sorted (infinite) sequence" is a well-defined, let alone useful concept (in the context of a programming library; in mathematics, that's totally fine of course!).

Depending on what you plan on doing with the resulting collection, you can use sorted sets:

```
generateSequence(0) { it + 1 }.windowed(size = 100, step = 1).
        toSortedSet(Comparator { o1, o2 -> o1.sum() - o2.sum() })
```

You defined a sequence of lists, and it's not per se clear how to order those.

Caveats:

- No longer lazy.
- No duplicates allowed; the Kotlin library seems to be missing a a multi set (or bag, or counted set, or ...) implementation. Easy to simulate by composing values in pairs with counters.
- Some operations are more expensive than one a linear sequence *without* ordering guarantee.

Comment: I don't agree. Java streams are similar but can have an attribute associated with them that says that the data is ORDERED or SORTED, among other attributes. If a sequence of objects is tagged as ordered, you can know that when you iterate through the sequence, objects that are equal are adjacent to each other, which means you only need to store the last object seen in order to produce a sequence of distinct objects. Yes, you are relying on the fact that the tag on the sequence is accurate, but you can do this with Java Streams.

Comment: The work around here is to simply keep track of last seen when iterating over the sequence.

Comment: @Mike Hmm, I was thinking about how to *convert* an arbitrary sequence/stream into an ordered one. That's a different (and harder) problem; of course, we can _assert_ that a given stream is ordered, and check this assertion dynamically.